# Let V,W be vector spaces over Q, and let T:V→W be a function. if the field Q is replaced with the field C, is it still a linear

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let V,W be vector spaces over Q, and let T:V→W be a function. 
a)Prove that if

T$(v_1+v_2)=T(v_1)+T(v_2)$
for all $v_1,v_2$∈V, then T is linear.

b) Does the statement in part (a) remain true if the field Q is replaced with the field C?

For part a) i just do T($(V_1+V_2)+(V_1'+V_2')$)=T(($V_1+V_1')+(V_2+V_2')$)=T$(V1+V1')+T(V2+V2')=T(v_1)+T(v_2)$

T$(k(V1+v2))=T(kv1+kv2)=kT(v1+v2)$  am i right to do this?, and how to answer the part b

Comment: In your final line you are pulling $k$ out of $T$ but that is what you need to prove. You are given that $T(v+w)=Tv+Tw$ but you must prove that $T(av)=aTv$.

Comment: i did pull out, T(k(v1+v2))=kT(v1+v2)

Comment: The point is, that $T$ is  not given to have the property that you can pull out. You will need to prove that you can pull out. That is, the step $T(kv_1+kv_2) = kT(v_1+v_2)$ is not correct without justification. To justify this step, you will need to show that $T(av) = aT(v)$ for every scalar $a$ and vector $v$. You will need to use the fact that $a$ is rational. For example, $T(2v) = 2T(v)$ follows by setting $v_1 = v_2$ in the statement you are asked to assume. Extend this to all integers, then to all rationals.

Comment: i think I got this ,in part B ,i can just do                                                F(nx)=nF(x),n∈Z , and then for 0≠n∈Z :
F(x)=f(n*x/n)=nF(1/n*x)⟹F(1/n*x)=1/nF(x)
and from here

F(m/n *x)=m F(1/n *x)=m/n F(x)